# Why won't Xcode output my new file?

Tags: c, xcode, macos

Basically I'm only trying to print the text "Kosher is best." into a new text file on my Mac using Xcode. It runs fine but never outputs my file. Could my Xcode settings be wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    FILE * fpointer;
    fpointer = fopen("kosher.txt", "w");

    fprintf(fpointer, "Kosher is best.");

    fclose(fpointer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. *Always* check if `fopen` succeeds. 2. Are you sure you looked in the right folder?

Comment: @Jongware how do you mean check if fopen succeeds? And yes I'm fairly sure. I searched for "kosher" in finder and had no results. (Using Mac by the way). Also checked in the same folder that my code file is in.

Comment: It could fail for any number of reasons. See `man fopen`: "Upon successful completion fopen(), fdopen(), and freopen() return a FILE pointer.  Otherwise,  NULL is returned and the global variable errno is set to indicate the error" or [any random online reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen).

Comment: (One Test Run Later) Just to be sure I compiled your program with `clang` (which I prefer over XCode). It runs without a hitch and creates the file in the folder in which the *executable* resides (which does **not** need to be the one for "the code"). All quite as expected. Any problems are therefore local to your system.

Comment: @DannyOhana Did you search for the file on your entire file system? Perhaps you are starting the find from the wrong folder. As a test, use an absolute path for your `fopen` (e.g. /tmp/kosher.txt"). Then you know exactly which directory the file will/should be created in.

Comment: @kaylum: just shut my system down for the night - should "~/Documents/kosher.txt" work? That folder should be available for freely reading and writing.

Comment: No, I don't think the `~` will work. That is a shell-ism. You need to give the full path. If you do then that should be ok.

Comment: @kaylum: pity... Usually my own programs use `argv` so I can use `~` whenever I want. Now I also recall I once wrote a `getenv` parser for exactly this purpose.

Comment: SOLVED: Did some searching and found this...

1. Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme
2. Click on the options tab
3. Check the box by Working Directory
4. Click the folder symbol to the right of the text box under Working Directory
5. Choose the folder you'd like your files to be inputted from and outputted to
6. Done

Comment: @Danny: if you found a working solution, your are [encouraged to add it as the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). That way it may help someone dealing with the same problem.